# When Importing Products Warning is thrown in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, product-import

I have edited the qunatity Field of 4 products .And I have imported that CSV the Following fields have imported succesfully. But I got a Following Warning message

**General system exception happened**

```
Warning: IntlDateFormatter::parse(): Date parsing failed in 
\vendor\magento\framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone.php on line 178
```

Comment: do you have a date in one of the columns in your csv?

Comment: No i have only Sku, Product_type ,Quantity